# What will I be charged with in Manhattan, New York?

Tags: criminal-law, fraud, new-york-state, theft, trespass

I conspired with Daisy to steal a NYSE work badge/access card from Sanjay and Daisy replaces his badge with a fake one. I impersonate Sanjay (make my appearance like his) and sneak into the NYSE with the work badge/ access card. I am caught by Mu (another employee) at the NYSE and he takes away Sanjay’s access card from me, but I have not been apprehended by the police. I have not gained any benefit from the use of the access card (nothing financial), except access to the workplace. Mu reports me to the police and files a complaint. 
What will I be charged with?

Criminal trespass in 3rd degree, criminal impersonation in 2nd degree, petit larceny by acquiring lost property. Anything else? Or are these wrong so far?

Keep in mind Mu and Sanjay have no idea I conspired with Daisy to steal the access card. Daisy’s fingerprints are on the fake access card, the one she gave to Sanjay.

Comment: Can we assume that this caper wasn't just for thrills, and that you had some deeper criminal purpose which was foiled when you got caught?  If so, I'd expect some charges of attempted X / conspiracy to X.

Comment: Are you asking about state charges, or federal?  Please add either the [tag:new-york] or [tag:united-states] tag respectively.

Comment: I have added the state tag. I do not believe this spills over to a federal issue. There is no white collar crime committed. There is NO deeper criminal purpose which is foiled, at least not to anyone’s knowledge. If you think this has federal criminal acts, then by all means state the federal charges in your answer.